# PowerShell - Net Use check if exists

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a Power-Shell script to remove connection without using the `net use * /delete`. Is that any way i can check on the connected Remote first before i proceed to drop it? I tried this, but its not working as i thought. I open to any suggestion.

```
$conns = net use
foreach ($con in ($conns | select Remote)) {
    if($con -eq "//MyServerB/C$") {
       net use "//MyServerB/C$" /delete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since net use is not a PowerShell cmdlet, you are not getting back an object with which you can filter with Select-Object. Instead you are getting back text. Additionally, net use on my system uses backslashes in the remote path instead of forward slashes and if you use double quotes you would have to escape the dollar sign so I would just use single quotes.

So your code would have to look like this:

```
$conns = net use
foreach ($con in $conns) {
    if($con -match '\\\\MyServerB\\C\$') {
       net use '\\MyServerB\C$' /delete
    }
}
```

As mklement0 mentioned in the comments, the above net use /delete command only works in that format if the remote path is not mapped as a drive letter. For example if the output looks like this:

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\fluidfs01\c$            Microsoft Windows Network
```

But if there is a drive letter (which is probably more likely), the disconnect command would have to be in the following format:

```
net use F: /delete
```

Comment: @mklement0. Thanks, I've updated the answer. Basically, if the remote path is associated with a drive letter, you are correct that you have to use the drive letter in the delete command. If there is not a local drive letter associated with it, you can delete using the UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

Well what i found is that net use returns an array so selecting a field doesn't work like you have written.

```
$c = net use
$c[6]
```

I have noted the output you are looking for starts from the 7th (6 in terms of array) element in the array and depending on how many results are returned it can go higher. The way you can know there are no more results is that the next element will contain the following message.

```
The command completed successfully.
```

You could loop starting element 7 and till you see that line. Then capture what ever is in between these two. That's all i have been able to work out so far. I will update if i can find a better way.

Comment: `net use` - like any console application - returns a stream of bytes typically interpreted as text.
It is _PowerShell_ that breaks _any_ external command's output into an _array of strings_, line by line, which facilitates processing the command's output in a PowerShell pipeline.
The approach you describe illustrates the fragility of text-based parsing and is best avoided in favor of native PowerShell commands, which are much more robust due to passing _objects_ through the pipeline, whose _properties_ provide unambiguous access to the data of interest.

Answer (score 0):

[Jon Dechiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6595659/jon-dechiro) contains helpful pointers and a viable solution based on `net use`.

<sup>Note: The following solution **assumes that the share in question is mapped to a *drive letter***.</sup>

Here's a ***mostly* pure PowerShell solution** that takes advantage of PowerShell sending *objects* through the pipeline (PSv3+), which is **preferable to parsing *text* returned by external commands**:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk | 
 Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 4 -and $_.ProviderName -eq '\\MyServerB\C$' } |
  ForEach-Object { net use $_.DeviceID /delete }
```

- `Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk` returns all filesystem drives known to the system as `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/cimv2/Win32_LogicalDisk]` objects.
- `Where-Object` filters the collection of drives based on the following criteria:

  - `$_.DriveType -eq 4` matches only network (mapped) drives.
  - `$_.ProviderName -eq '\\MyServerB\C$'` matches the drive's UNC share path against the specified path;
    note the use of a single-quoted string, which ensures that the `$` is treated as a literal.
- `ForEach-Object { net use $_.DeviceID /delete }` then simply invokes `net use` to delete the drive (if the filter stage of the pipeline doesn't find the drive of interest, no action is taken).

---

Note: A *pure* PowerShell solution that uses [`Remove-PSDrive`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849760.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to remove a mapped drive as follows *should* work, according to the docs, but as of PSv5 doesn't, UNLESS the mapping was originally established with `New-PSDrive`:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk | 
 Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 4 -and $_.ProviderName -eq '\\MyServerB\C$' } |
  Remove-PSDrive
```

Similarly, I couldn't get [`Remove-SmbMapping`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635700%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to work.